# ActiveRecord : LEFT OUTER self-JOIN with conditions on joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an ActiveRecord class with a reflexive association (*note : class names are redacted for non-disclosure reasons*) :

```
   class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base

     belongs_to :parent, 
                class_name: 'Thing'

     has_many :children, 
              class_name:  'Thing', 
              foreign_key: :parent_id

     scope :children, ->{ where(arel_table[:parent_id].not_eq(nil)) }

   end
```

**I want to get all children, left outer joined to their parent, with an additional condition on the parent if it's present, while still eager-loading the parent.**

Usually in this case i do something like :

```
 Thing.includes(:other_thing).merge(OtherThing.some_scope)
```

But it's not possible in this case : as this is a self-join, if I merge a scope from `Thing` the condition will apply to the children things, not the parents.

I tried to do this in raw SQL :

```
  scope :some_scope, ->{
    children.joins(<<-SQL).references(:parent)
      LEFT OUTER JOIN things AS parents
        ON  things.parent_id = parents.id 
        AND parents.some_field IN ('foo', 'bar')
    SQL
  }
```

The query is OK, but it seems that the parent does not get eager-loaded (n+1 queries when trying to `map(&:parent)` on this scope).

For now, my more-or-less working solution is to use a sub query (plucking ids that match the parent condition, then selecting children with `parent_id IN` this set), but I'd like to know if there is a more appropriate / elegant one.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to do this using `merge` (which seems to insist on using the model table_name), but you can do this using `includes` and building the condition around the expected alias - you'll need to modify this alias according to your own naming:

```
User.includes(:parent).
      where('parents_users.some_field IN (?)', ['foo', 'bar']).
      references(:parents_users)
```

However, you may need to watch out for NULL parent id's since the condition will be added to the WHERE clause and not the LEFT JOIN itself:

```
User.includes(:parent).
      where('parents_users.some_field IN (?) OR parents_users.id IS NULL', ['foo', 'bar']).
      references(:parents_users)
```

This should perform all eager loading properly.

Comment: +1, thanks for looking into this. I did not mention this solution, but I tested it, too (I was just missing the references part). I guess that's an improvement over what I have now, but I'm not very fond of "guessing" what kind of alias AR will pull out of its magician hat...